# CodeIgniter -> Submitting a form into database

Tags: php, html, database, forms, codeigniter

Creating my own application to learn CodeIgniter, by following CI documentation, i can't post my data into db.

I'm using create.php:

```
<p class="h4 mb-4 text-center"><?= $title ?></p>

<label>Username</label>
<input type="text" id="textInput" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Your username" name="username">

<label for="textInput">Title</label>
<input class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Your title" name="title">

<label>Your message</label>
<textarea class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Your message content" name="body"></textarea>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">
    <select class="browser-default custom-select mb-4" id="select" name="genre">
        <option selected="">Choose your Genre</option>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-2">
        <input class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Your age" name="age">
    </div>
</div>
<select class="browser-default custom-select mb-4" name="platform">
    <option value="" disabled="" selected="">Choose your Platform</option>
    <option value="1">Snapchat</option>
    <option value="2">Kik</option>
    <option value="3">Instagram</option>
    <option value="4">Telegram</option>
</select>

<button class="btn btn-info my-4 btn-block" type="submit">Sign up</button>

<div class="text-center">
    <p>By clicking
        <em>Sign up</em> you agree to our
        <a href="<?php echo base_url('tou'); ?>" target="_blank">terms of use</a>.
    </p>
</div>
```

This is the controller:

```
public function create(){
        $data['title'] = 'Add your Username';

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('title', 'Title', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('body', 'Body', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('genre', 'Genre', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('platform', 'Platform', 'required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('age', 'Age', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
            $this->load->view('templates/header');
            $this->load->view('posts/create', $data);
            $this->load->view('templates/footer');
        } else {
            $this->post_model->create_post();
            redirect('posts');
        }
    }
```

This is the model:

```
public function create_post(){
        $slug = url_title($this->input->post('title'));

        $data = array(
            'title' => $this->input->post('title'),
            'slug' => $slug,
            'body' => $this->input->post('body'),
            'username' => $this->input->post('username'),
            'genre' => $this->input->post('genre'),
            'age' => $this->input->post('age'),
            'platform' => $this->input->post('platform'),
        );
        return $this->db->insert('posts', $data);
    }
```

I've added as well in autoload (libraries->form_validation) and (helper->form).
I've already tested everything before those codes, and it was working fine. The problem is that those data in HTML i want to send them into db, but even validator works on blank forms (submitting without content) or inserting content, it's just realod the page, as it should redirecting it to posts url.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Show me the result of `var_dump($_POST); die;` at the beginning of your `create()`!

Comment: @SherifSalah 
C:\wamp64\www\application\views\posts\create.php:1:
array (size=0)
  empty

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, but there's no `<form>` tags in your view, so your form will actually do nothing. You need to let the browser know where you want the form data posted to. Since you are autoloading the form helper, instead of writing the form tags you could `<?php echo form_open('yourcontroller/create'); ?>` before the form and `<?php echo form_close(); ?>` after the submit button and have CI create the necessary HTML elements for you

Answer (score 0):

where your post method in view ?

Ex :

```
<form method="post" name="from_submit" action="">
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add form

```
 <form method="post" name="myform" action="">
//Your form code---

</form>
```